# What icon should be set as form's icon?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, icons

I have a WinForms application. I've set up the executable's icon (with at least 16x16 and 32x32 formats) in project settings and it is successfully shown in Explorer and elsewhere for .exe file.

How can I set this icon as form's icon (`Form.Icon` property or something)? It may be used in form's header at left and it will be used to show form in taskbar.

As I know, `System.Drawing.Icon` can't be created with multiple icon formats, but.. when user has his taskbar with 'small icons' enabled, the icon for taskbar should be 16x16. When this option is disabled, it should be 32x32. If icon has wrong size, the windows will scale it and it will look terrible.

`Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon` gives me only one format (32x32). P/Invoking `ExtractIconEx` gives me both formats (16x16 and 32x32), but I unable to combine it in one `System.Drawing.Icon` instance to set to `Form.Icon`.

Of course, I can set the icon with form's properties from .ico file, but it will give me the resource duplication: one icon is stored in PE as executable's icon and another is stored as .NET resource.

Again, the question is: what settings I should use to make the exe's icon to be form's icon and work as it should with any taskbar settings?

Comment: Use a program like IcoFX just to make sure you have all bitness and dimensions for your icon into that one single file. Then once the icon is set to the form icon it uses the same for taskbar icon and resize accordingly without doing anything.

Comment: I am sure that my .ico is correct. How I should set this icon to form without duplicating it in .NET resources?

Comment: In the project resources go to the icon tab and add you icon there. Then in the form simply click the icon property and select from the resources list you icon and that's it.

Comment: @Franck it will lead to resource duplication as I said in question post. It is not desired

Comment: Your executables icon should be in multiple formats (16x16, 32x32, 64x64 and 256x256). Use that multi-sized icon for everything. There are online services that convert PNG, JPG etc. bitmaps to multi-format icons. Search "Icon Converter" o similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the default icon handling routines in Windows and .Net don't extract multisize icons from modules well. The `Icon` class has tricky usage where it pulls in all the data from an icon file and then only uses one size, and you can create a new `Icon` object from that original `Icon` for a different size and it will share the data and extract the nearest size. Unfortunately methods to easily work with multi size icons aren't really included.

Here is code that will let you do what you want from Code Project, written for exactly your purpose: assigning the multisize icon from the EXE file to your forms.

[Assigning an applications icon to all the forms in the application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29923/Assigning-an-application-s-icon-to-all-forms-in-th)

Once you have the library added to your project, you can just assign the singleton property `HostIcon` to your form's `icon` property:

```
this.icon = Cliver.IconRoutines.HostIcon;
```

Comment: ``Icon.GetAssociatedIcon`` extracts only 32x32 format, but I need both.

Comment: I assume you mean `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon`?

Comment: Oops. Yes. it is. i had to copypaste instead of writing:)